# about angularJS directives

Tags: angularjs

I write a directive called ValidateChineseDirective.

```
define(function(){
    'use strict';
    return function(module){
        module.directive('validateChinese',function(){
            return {
                restrict:'A',
                require:'ngModel',
                link:function(scope,ele,attr,ngModel){
                      if (!ngModel) return;
                      var maxlength = -1;
                      attr.$observe('validateChinese', function(value) {
                        var intVal = parseInt(value,10);
                        maxlength = isNaN(intVal) ? -1 : intVal;
                        ngModel.$validate();
                      });
                        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue){
                            var valueArray = viewValue.split("");
                            var reg = /[\u4E00-\u9FA5\uF900-\uFA2D]/;
                            var len=0;
                            for(var i=0;i<valueArray.length;i++){
                                len += reg.test(valueArray[i])?4:1;
                            }
                            if(len<=maxlength){
                                ngModel.$setValidity('validateChinese',true);
                            }else{
                                ngModel.$setValidity('validateChinese',false);
                            }
                            return viewValue;
                        });
                }
            }
        })
    }
})
```

html:

```
<input type="text" name="approvedDocNo" validate_chinese="4" ng-model="fundMaintenanceVM.editData.approvedDocNo" class="form-control">
```

the reg was used for matching chinese.
I found that whether input space at the begin of the input box or at the end of it.
ngModel.$parsers.push didn't trigger until type a character.
furthermore,when ngModel.$parsers.push triggered, viewValue didn't contain the space which is at the end of this input box or at the end of it.Does somebody can help me ,thx.

Comment: Can u create a simple fiddle?

Comment: I'm sorry ,I don't know how to create this simple fiddle properly.

Comment: Did the below code work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `ng-trim="false"` to the input element which used your directive.

---

The reason is that: Angular sets `ng-trim` to true **by default**, which trims white space in input boxes, and leads no change with `ngModel`.

```js
angular.module("app", []).directive('validateChinese', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, ele, attr, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel) return;
      var maxlength = -1;
      attr.$observe('validateChinese', function(value) {
        var intVal = parseInt(value, 10);
        maxlength = isNaN(intVal) ? -1 : intVal;
        ngModel.$validate();
      });
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
        var valueArray = viewValue.split("");
        var reg = /[\u4E00-\u9FA5\uF900-\uFA2D]/;
        var len = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++) {
          len += reg.test(valueArray[i]) ? 4 : 1;
        }
        if (len <= maxlength) {
          ngModel.$setValidity('validateChinese', true);
        } else {
          ngModel.$setValidity('validateChinese', false);
        }
        console.log('ngModel.$parsers.push fired.');
        return viewValue;
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <input type="text" name="approvedDocNo" validate_chinese="4" ng-model="approvedDocNo" ng-trim="false" class="form-control">
  {{approvedDocNo}}
</div>
```